# jQuery or Javascript Simulate mobile double Tab screen resize

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mobile

UPDATE BELOW:

I need help with calling a DoubleTap on mobile devices that will resize the screen contents to fit everything on the page.

Without explaining all the fine detailed reasons why I need this I will say I am calling a script that updates a photo but it makes the photo TOO BIG.

The users can fix the size issue by simply double clicking on the document. Once the users double clicks on the document then it resizes on both Android and Mobile if it goes off screen... but I would like to do it for them so they don't have to for tidiness sake.

**How can I simulate a double click automatically for mobile devices without the users clicking on the document so I can resize content to fit on screen?** I would like the page to just resize to fit once the image updates and shows itself to be too big.

The 1st image below shows what the page looks like after the script is called and makes the image go off screen. The second image shows what it will look like after the users double clicks on the document to resize it to fit. I would like to do this automatically for them.

REASON WHY I CAN'T USE CSS OR a responsive image. The code is overlaying two images and makes a profile frame. If I resize it or play with the css then the final image is messed up when I render it. I tried all these options for hours. My only thought it maybe I can simulate a MOBILE DOUBLE CLICK ON DOCUMENT TO RESIZE feature. Is this even possible?

Thanks

UPDATE: I found out that the css zoom: 80% etc will work. but now I just have to calculate the zoom percentage based off of how big the picture is. The image will always have a 512 width. How would I get the percentage based off of the screenwidth compared to 512px etc?

[image: Mobile view after script runs. The picture goes out of frame.]

[image: Same page but after a double click on the webpage then mobile resizes to fit.]

Comment: Have you tried this? https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Comment: Yes, thanks I have tried. $('.container-fluid').dblclick(); $(window').dblclick(); $(document).dblclick(); and nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

To get zoom as a percentage based on pic vs device width:

```js
let picWidth = $('#my-img').width();
let deviceWidth = $(window).width();
let zoom = (deviceWidth / picWidth) * 100;
```

If the device is 410px and the pic is 512px, the zoom would be (410 / 512) * 100 ~ 80%. Just make sure that the pic width isn't 0.